# 401 Unauthorized when authenticating using referer

Tags: php, curl, http-referer

I am trying to use an API which says to use it in a custom application to set a custom referer. Here's the official text:

> The API requires (if enabled) a token for read operations to be send
>   to allow request, otherwise "Missing 'key' parameter" message will be
>   returned.
>
> The security module will use the referrer heading ("referer" in Java,
>   HTTP_REFERER in PHP) of the request to identify and filter the
>   authorized domains.

I can currently log in to the web interface by using a special URL provided which seems to set the session and then redirects to the main URL. If I try navigating to the main URL directly without first using the special URL, I get a 401 error, as expected (afterwards, I can just use the main URL)

The key given below the text above is something like: `http://example.com/api/?key=secretkeyhere`

While I can use the API using the GUI tool in my web browser as described above, I can't figure out how to connect to it programatically. I have tried using both curl in Linux as well as curl in PHP. Both have failed.

curl from terminal:

```
curl --header http://example.com/api/?key=secretkeyhere http://example.com/api/search?query=terms*
```

curl in PHP:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/api/search?query=terms');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://example.com/api/?key=secretkeyhere');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "$html";
?>
```

I continue to get:

> Unauthorized This server could not verify that you are authorized to
>   access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong
>   credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand
>   how to supply the credentials required.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is the API not set up correctly? I've read the `man` page for cURL and it seems like this is exactly what I should be doing.

Comment: is that autoreferer needed?

Comment: @Oli I tried it both w/ and w/o - that's just where I ended.

Comment: Every API is different. Supply us with a link to the documentation.

Comment: @EternalHour Unfortunately, it's not something I'm at liberty to share. However, I can provide you with snippets or excerpts. Unfortunately, that's pretty much all that's provided, not much to go on.